# what is the difference between /etc/issue.net and /etc/issue

Tags: linux, redhat

What are their purpose as they have the same content ?

```
[me@myserver ~]$ cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m

[me@myserver ~]$ cat /etc/issue.net
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Both `/etc/issue.net` and `/etc/issue` are used to display a banner (e.g. welcome line/ warning..) to SSH users before the login prompt:

- `/etc/issue.net` is shown to the users who connect from the network.
- `/etc/issue` is shown to both **local users** and network users **unless** `/etc/issue.net` is present and configured.

Also, to configure them to be displayed when you login via SSH, you need to uncomment `#Banner` and specify the desired filename at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, like:

```
Banner /etc/issue.net
```

The filename `/etc/issue.net` is the historical location for pre-login banners for network logins using protocols like `telnet` or `rlogin`. Some Unix vendors had a version of `telnetd`, `rshd` and/or `rlogind` that used `/etc/issue` for network logins too; others made it configurable like `sshd` does now.